# web pages with dynamic content/component

Tags: web

What is the programming model (language) behind the web pages that dynamically add contents based on the user interaction. For example, if you visit this [site](https://www.converto.io/), there is a text box which user has to put some input. Then it will open some other components, e.g. a button and config page. As you can see the URL remains intact. The source pages shows that it uses JavaScript. So, what is the first step to follow that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific language for the web, there's a lot. It really isn't very different from developing a regular desktop application. It just exists within the browser sandbox.

This question is for too general to be answered with any specifics. If you really want to make an interactive website - you just need a bit of html, css and some javascript.

Here's an example of some code that submits a form with an input:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_form_submit